# Unable to relay recipient in non-accepted domain

Tags: wamp, wampserver, mantis

All emails with the domain **@mycompany.com** are sent successfully. But, if MantisBT wants to send an email to anyone else, for example **@othercontractor.com**, or **@gmail.com**, etc , the email is not sent.

In addition, a collateral damage of this problematic email is that it will get stuck in **"MySqlDatabase/mantis_email_table"** and all the emails after this problematic email in that table won't be sent. So, to fix it, I have to manually delete that entry in the table. It is not very convenient when I want to add contractor who has his own email domain in our bug tracker.

This the email configuration in: **/path_to_mantis_bt/config/config_inc.php**

```
// Email Configuration
$g_email_send_using_cronjob = ON;
$g_allow_signup = ON; //allows the users to sign up for a new account
$g_enable_email_notification = ON; //enables the email messages

$g_phpMailer_method = PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP;
$g_smtp_host = 'edge.mycompany.com';
$g_smtp_connection_mode = '';
$g_smtp_port = 25;
$g_administrator_email = 'myname@mycompany.com';
$g_from_email = 'myname@mycompany.com';
$g_return_path_email = 'myname@mycompany.com';
$g_from_name = 'Mantis Bug Tracker';
```

I should mention that we are hosting MantisBT on our own server **Microsoft Server 2012 R2** and WAMP(latest version).

**The error:** 2018-01-08 10:24 PST MAIL email_api.php:1379 email_send() ERROR: Message could not be sent - SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: xxx@gmail.com: 5.7.54 SMTP; Unable to relay recipient in non-accepted domain

Comment: I dont think this is a WAMPServer issue. This is the important part of that error message _Unable to relay recipient in non-accepted domain_ Your company email server is not being properly recognised as a legitimate email server. Check with your email server admins

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, but I used sendmail instead of using the WAMP/SMTP.

[To install SENDMAIL on WAMP, I followed these instructions](http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/)

This the email configuration in: **/path_to_mantis_bt/config/config_inc.php**

```
$g_allow_signup    = ON;  //allows the users to sign up for a new account
$g_enable_email_notification = ON; //enables the email messages
$g_phpMailer_method = PHPMAILER_METHOD_SENDMAIL; //If not using sendmail, use: PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP;
$g_smtp_host = 'edge.mycompany.com';
$g_smtp_connection_mode = 'tls';
$g_smtp_port = 587;
$g_smtp_username = 'xxx'; // my username for email myname@mycompany.com
$g_smtp_password = 'xxx'; // my password for email myname@mycompany.com
$g_administrator_email  = 'myname@mycompany.com';
$g_webmaster_email      = 'myname@mycompany.com';
$g_from_email           = 'myname@mycompany.com';
$g_return_path_email    = 'myname@mycompany.com';
$g_from_name = 'Mantis Bug Tracker';

// Log configuration
$g_log_level = LOG_EMAIL | LOG_EMAIL_RECIPIENT | LOG_FILTERING | LOG_AJAX;
$g_log_destination = 'file:/wamp64/logs/mantis.log';
?>
```

IF you follow the link above, you will know how to update **php.ini** and **sendmail.ini** . Update these 2 files with the information in config_inc.php.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, we were sending out emails from an application and there was a user bcced (hardcoded in the code) which was not in the domain and hence it failed

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue once I changed to @newdomain.com.
In my case I found suggestion on the web to clear cache of my browser. I did and all start working.
Basically, you need to reload all config files from scratch with new globals...
At least it worked for me.

Cheers.